# Re Install an app in android programmatically and clear the data too

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to update my application. For that I am trying to Re Install my application from a local path.

```
public void installApplication(String fileLocalPath){

        Uri installpackageURI = Uri.parse("package:ABC");
        Intent installIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, installpackageURI);
        installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileLocalPath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

       //   deleteDatabase(DatabaseName);
       //   startActivity(installIntent);

    }
```

It gives a user Alert for confirmation of installation. Now if i delete the data by call to deleteDatabase function(commented in above code) before starting intent, and then if i cancel the installation the data is lost.

Otherwise i am not able to clear the data.

Please suggest me some way to clear data while updating. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you still facing any problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think right way to handle this by upgrading database version and writing following code in your database helper.

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

For more info Follow Note Pad example in API Demos.